# MySQL Exclude Certain Fields in Database

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm somewhat new to MySQL and come from a Javascript background. I'm trying to write a query to pull in all domain records unless that domain is the root domain and is a domain type of RS. How can I do something like this?

`SELECT * FROM Domains WHERE DomainId = ? AND !(RecordType = 'NS' && Domain = rootDomain)`

Comment: as we don't know your table structure and also not which data are in it, it is hard, but you can enter yourquery in workbench it will show that ot os flawed and try to improve the query your self.

Comment: How is the root domain defined in your table? The query you posted looks for a column called `rootDomain`, and compares it to the `Domain` column in the same row.

Comment: Maybe it should be `Domain = '.'` since `.` is the name of the root domain in DNS.

Comment: The DB information is not as important as the syntax I'm trying to achieve. I am looking for a way to pull in all items, unless an item matches multiple fields in the DB. The snippet could have read ```SELECT * FROM Things WHERE Id = ? AND !(Column1 = true && Column2 = 'foo') ```